# NSIS switch with multi-criteria case

Tags: scripting, switch-statement, nsis

May I do in NSIS `switch` with multi-criteria `case` like in JavaScript?

```
 ${Switch} $0
   ${Case} 2
     DetailPrint "Connection to server failed: $0"
     Abort      
   ${Break}      
   ${Case} 1          
   ${Case} 3
   ${Case} "timeout"   
     DetailPrint "Database creating failed: $0"
     Abort   
   ${Break}          
 ${EndSwitch}
```

Comment: Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: I don`t get a compiler error. It works.